# Detect specific keypresses in GUI

Tags: python, linux, gtk, keypress

I'm looking for a way in Gtk/Python to have an app listen for keypresses and when some of the special keys are pressed, perform an action (recreate a menu with different labels, since it's an appindicator). I can't really find a way to do it though. If anyone is able to help, I'd be thankful.

Comment: Could you explain a little more when you say special keys? Do you mean like `Ctrl`, `Alt` etc? Do you want to detect them along with mouse clicks or only when pressed without any mouse clicks involved?

Comment: @another.anon.coward I mean more about num/caps/scrolllock and insert. I want them to be detected whenever they are pressed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably need to handle the ["key-press-event"](http://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/GtkWidget.html#GtkWidget-key-press-event) (and probably also ["key-release-event"](http://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/GtkWidget.html#GtkWidget-key-release-event)) of GtkWidget. PyGtk knows [about it](http://www.pygtk.org/docs/pygtk/class-gtkwidget.html#signal-gtkwidget--key-press-event).

It should be inside some "windowing" widget, so you may need to use [GtkEventBox](http://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/GtkEventBox.html) as a container.

Comment: Thanks. If you've got a minute, would you mind putting a simple example for how would this be used? I tried doing something with on_key_press_event and on_key_press, but I've no idea how to get them to activate, since this isn't in a window.

Comment: It should be some windowing widget. And giving a complete example will take me more than an hour, I don't have that much time to help you.

Comment: Thanks, just pointing to that should be enough. Simply couldn't figure into what I should have put it.