# Make pressing the "enter" key call a function in gtk3

Tags: python, button, gtk, key, gtk3

I'm trying to make it so that when i press the enter key it calls the `click()` function, or activates a press on the `calculateButton`, i apolagise for my horrific coding, i'm self taught, so its not neat or correct in any way, but it works...

Code:

```
import gi
import math
gi.require_version('Gtk', '3.0')
from gi.repository import Gtk

class TableWindow(Gtk.Window):

    def __init__(self):

        Gtk.Window.__init__(self, title="Injection Time Calculator")

        table = Gtk.Table(7, 2, True)
        self.add(table)

        sizeLabel = Gtk.Label("WALL SIZE")
        widthLabel = Gtk.Label("WIDTH")
        heightLabel = Gtk.Label("HEIGHT")
        fsLabel = Gtk.Label("FLAT STUD?")
        ecLabel = Gtk.Label("EC?")
        injLabel = Gtk.Label()

        heightEntry=Gtk.Entry()
        widthEntry=Gtk.Entry()

        sizeBox = Gtk.ComboBoxText()

        sizeBox.append("1","90")
        sizeBox.append("2","140")
        sizeBox.append("3","219")

        fsCheckButton=Gtk.CheckButton()
        ecCheckButton=Gtk.CheckButton()

        calculateButton=Gtk.Button.new_with_label("CALCULATE INJECTION TIME")
        calculateButton.connect("clicked", self.Click)


        table.attach(sizeLabel, 0, 1, 0, 1)
        table.attach(widthLabel, 0, 1, 1, 2)
        table.attach(heightLabel, 0, 1, 2, 3)
        table.attach(fsLabel, 0, 1, 3, 4)
        table.attach(injLabel, 0, 2, 6, 7)
        table.attach(ecLabel, 0, 1, 4, 5)

        table.attach(calculateButton, 0, 2, 5, 6)

        table.attach(widthEntry, 1, 2, 1, 2)
        table.attach(heightEntry, 1, 2, 2, 3)

        table.attach(sizeBox, 1, 2, 0, 1)

        table.attach(fsCheckButton, 1, 2, 3, 4)
        table.attach(ecCheckButton, 1, 2, 4, 5)

        global sizeLabel
        global heightEntry
        global widthEntry
        global fsCheckButton
        global ecCheckButton
        global sizeBox
        global injLabel


    def Click(self, calculateButton):

        studWidth=sizeBox.get_active_text()

        areaHeight=heightEntry.get_text()
        areaWidth=widthEntry.get_text()

        if fsCheckButton.get_active():
            if studWidth=="90":
                areaWidth=float(areaWidth)-59
            elif studWidth=="140":
                areaWidth=float(areaWidth)-38
            elif studWidth=="219":
                areaWidth=float(areaWidth)-24.3

        if ecCheckButton.get_active():
            if studWidth=="90":
                areaWidth=float(areaWidth)-2*(59)
            elif studWidth=="140":
                areaWidth=float(areaWidth)-2*38
            elif studWidth=="219":
                areaWidth=float(areaWidth)-2*24.3

        timeVar=float(studWidth)*10.7/140
        injTime=((float(areaWidth)*float(areaHeight)*float(timeVar))/1000000)
        a= str( 'INJECTION TIME IS '+str(injTime)[:7]+' SECONDS OR '+str((math.ceil(injTime*5))/5)+' ROUNDED')
        injLabel.set_text(a)

        fsCheckButton.set_active(False)
        ecCheckButton.set_active(False)

win = TableWindow()
win.connect("delete-event", Gtk.main_quit)
win.show_all()
Gtk.main()
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Detect specific keypresses in GUI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13713347/detect-specific-keypresses-in-gui)

Comment: Unrelated, but `main_quit` should be connected to the `destroy` event, not `delete-event`.

Answer (score 1):

This is assuming you want to press `enter` in a GtkEntry to calculate the new numbers:

```
import gi
import math
gi.require_version('Gtk', '3.0')
from gi.repository import Gtk

class TableWindow(Gtk.Window):

    def __init__(self):

        Gtk.Window.__init__(self, title="Injection Time Calculator")

        table = Gtk.Table(7, 2, True)
        self.add(table)

        self.sizeLabel = Gtk.Label("WALL SIZE")
        widthLabel = Gtk.Label("WIDTH")
        heightLabel = Gtk.Label("HEIGHT")
        fsLabel = Gtk.Label("FLAT STUD?")
        ecLabel = Gtk.Label("EC?")
        self.injLabel = Gtk.Label()

        self.heightEntry=Gtk.Entry()
        self.heightEntry.connect("activate", self.calculate)
        self.widthEntry=Gtk.Entry()
        self.widthEntry.connect("activate", self.calculate)

        self.sizeBox = Gtk.ComboBoxText()

        self.sizeBox.append("1","90")
        self.sizeBox.append("2","140")
        self.sizeBox.append("3","219")

        self.fsCheckButton=Gtk.CheckButton()
        self.ecCheckButton=Gtk.CheckButton()

        calculateButton=Gtk.Button.new_with_label("CALCULATE INJECTION TIME")
        calculateButton.connect("clicked", self.calculate)


        table.attach(self.sizeLabel, 0, 1, 0, 1)
        table.attach(widthLabel, 0, 1, 1, 2)
        table.attach(heightLabel, 0, 1, 2, 3)
        table.attach(fsLabel, 0, 1, 3, 4)
        table.attach(self.injLabel, 0, 2, 6, 7)
        table.attach(ecLabel, 0, 1, 4, 5)

        table.attach(calculateButton, 0, 2, 5, 6)

        table.attach(self.widthEntry, 1, 2, 1, 2)
        table.attach(self.heightEntry, 1, 2, 2, 3)

        table.attach(self.sizeBox, 1, 2, 0, 1)

        table.attach(self.fsCheckButton, 1, 2, 3, 4)
        table.attach(self.ecCheckButton, 1, 2, 4, 5)


    def calculate (self, widget):
        studWidth=self.sizeBox.get_active_text()

        areaHeight=self.heightEntry.get_text()
        areaWidth=self.widthEntry.get_text()

        if self.fsCheckButton.get_active():
            if studWidth=="90":
                areaWidth=float(areaWidth)-59
            elif studWidth=="140":
                areaWidth=float(areaWidth)-38
            elif studWidth=="219":
                areaWidth=float(areaWidth)-24.3

        if self.ecCheckButton.get_active():
            if studWidth=="90":
                areaWidth=float(areaWidth)-2*(59)
            elif studWidth=="140":
                areaWidth=float(areaWidth)-2*38
            elif studWidth=="219":
                areaWidth=float(areaWidth)-2*24.3

        timeVar=float(studWidth)*10.7/140
        injTime=((float(areaWidth)*float(areaHeight)*float(timeVar))/1000000)
        a= str( 'INJECTION TIME IS '+str(injTime)[:7]+' SECONDS OR '+str((math.ceil(injTime*5))/5)+' ROUNDED')
        self.injLabel.set_text(a)

        self.fsCheckButton.set_active(False)
        self.ecCheckButton.set_active(False)

win = TableWindow()
win.connect("destroy", Gtk.main_quit)
win.show_all()
Gtk.main()
```

I have changed a few things to make your code a bit better.

Answer (score 0):

The documentation of [Gtk.Window.set_default](https://lazka.github.io/pgi-docs/#Gtk-3.0/classes/Window.html#Gtk.Window.set_default) tells you how to set the widget that gets the focus by default. Hitting enter when the focus is on a button just triggers the `clicked` signal of that button.

Being activated from the mouse or the keyboard is handled the same way and is transparent, so as you have already connected your signal to it, will have nothing else special to do.